# how to get pdftk to burst to source file name plus page number?

Tags: pdftk

How can I use pdftk to burst to the same filename as the source file plus a number?

Sample input

```
source.pdf
```

Desired output

```
source-1.pdf (it is ok if page number has leading zeroes, but not required)
source-2.pdf
```

Maybe I could use a .bat file to substitute the source filename?  I have no idea how to do this.  Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done like the following:

pdftk source.pdf burst output source-%d.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the pdftk command into a batch file.  This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set file=%1
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
    set prefix=%%~ni
)
set outname=%prefix%-%%02d.pdf
pdftk.exe %file% burst output %outname%
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pdftk server version

Allow for adding the path to environment variables

This can be done like the following:

Open windows cmd prompt

pdftk source.pdf burst

or

pdftk source.pdf burst output -%d.pdf